# writing text file using java script

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I was given a task  to enhance a system. The system is use for auditing a company property using the barcode scanner. The system use a ASP including the barcode scanner main program. They want me to include a offline scanning using the barcode scanner because some part of the company premises have no wifi access. I use the LocalStorage in html5 then suddenly i realize that the browser use by barcode scanner is a very old version of internet explorer(ie4). I research for alternative for LocalStorage then i found the [Jstorage](http://www.jstorage.info/) but still no luck because the the JStorage not supported IE4. Then one of my colleague suggest to me to use the text file as a temporary storage. Some of my research, they use the ActiveXObject and New File. The ActiveXObject supported by IE4?. If not what other method that i can temporary use to store data. I already use the Cookies but when the page refresh in barcode scanner browser cookies is being remove.